# Program using named pipe in background doesn't close properly

Tags: c, bash, pipe, named-pipes, named

I am trying to write program which part is communication using named pipe (fifo). When I am running writer and reader program in infinite loop (writer in background) in bash script, some time writer program is not closing properly by what I receive bad results.

There is a simple code which I try to use in my program too:

writer.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

reader.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    ./writer &
    ./reader
done
```

Could you help me to do this properly or maybe have you another idea how to do this?

Regards

Comment: Looks racy to me. I don't see where you ensure the fifo is already created when the reader tries to `open()` it.

Comment: I understand you, but when I do this it will work properly every time? This is only a piece of my all program and I need always good pipe communication in this program. Maybe you have another idea how to run this programs? For example not in background but in other way to work properly every time

Comment: Well, step one would be to not throw away the return values of the functions you call.